# A question about exporting a C++ class to C

Tags: c++, c

I've been reading about exporting a C++ class so that C can use it. I've followed this good [example](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.8) from Parashift, and a question came out.

To hold the memory allocated to the C++ class, we define the following structure

```
typedef struct A A;
```

So that `A*` can point to the address of the class A. My question is: does it matter of which type is this pointer? For example, couldn't we typedef something like:

```
typedef double A;
```

Since it's probably the C++ code that will be responsible for allocating and deallocating memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you shouldn't use `void*` by this. A pointer to an incomplete type `struct A` is a much better technique. This avoids that you mix pointers to different opaque types by accident. If you'd `typedef` it to `void` you could assign a pointer of your opaque type to any other data pointer. Probably not what you want.

Using an incomplete type gives you a bit of type safety for no cost at all.

Answer (score 2):

Opaque pointers are best declared as `void*`.

This is often known as the [*Pimpl idiom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimpl).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `void` type for anything which is intended to be opaque like this. Using a typedef of an undefined struct is ok in that its name can give you a sense of what it really points to.

Comment: @Nim That's right, `void` isn't really a type as such. You can't declare a variable of type `void` for example.